# How to add three Shortcut keys ( Ctrl + Shift + C) in Java Swing Menubar?

Tags: java, swing, menuitem, keyevent, jmenuitem

I want to add shortcut keys in Java Swing Menubar. Below is what I have tried.

```java
jMenuItem1.setText("Create");
jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

Here I want three `KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK`, and `KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK`.

Comment: Have you tried the swing tutorial on the java website?

Comment: Please do remove that word BOSS from your question, the first thing comes to my mind is regarding JBOSS Application Server, moreover it doesn't gives a nice interpretation to your question.

Answer (score 7):

```
jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK+ALT_MASK)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,java.awt.Event.CTRL_MASK | java.awt.Event.SHIFT_MASK));
```

Comment: StackOverflow's best practices suggest to explain the proposed solutions. Posting just code is not a good thing, you should always explain WHY your solution works.

Answer (score 3):

KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, 21);

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(int, int)

Read about the modifiers and you'll know what the 21 (or 2 and the 1) is for...

Comment: I think Avram has a more correct answer.
I didn't exactly understand the javadocs myself. :/

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java Menu Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#mnemonic):

> To specify an accelerator you must use a KeyStroke object, which combines a key (specified by a KeyEvent constant) and a modifier-key mask (specified by an ActionEvent constant).

The referenced "modifier-key mask" is created from multiple ActionEvents via bitwise operations, so the bitwise OR specifying multiple events in the `setAccelerator()` method does the same thing.

### On Windows Only:

```java
jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,
                         java.awt.Event.CTRL_MASK | java.awt.Event.SHIFT_MASK));
```

---

### Cross-platform:

To enable this cross-platform (i.e. to use the `Command` button on a Mac instead of `Control`), simply replace the `java.awt.Event.CTRL_MASK` with:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask(); // Java 9 or older
```

or

```java
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx(); // Java 10 or newer
```

for a final setAccelerator that looks like

```java
jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,
                         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx() | 
                         java.awt.Event.SHIFT_MASK));
```

On a Mac you'll also notice that the Accelerator text in the menu itself shows the CMD symbol, too, while on Windows it'll still show CTRL (e.g. CMD+S vs. CTRL+S).